# Updating GMap.NET Marker Image in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gmap.net

I can change my markers position with

```
markers.Markers[2].Position = new PointLatLng(30.0000, 30.00000);
```

but how can i change marker icon with setting a varible like above?
I am declaring points as

```
GMap.NET.WindowsForms.GMapMarker marker3 =
                new GMap.NET.WindowsForms.Markers.GMarkerGoogle(
                    new GMap.NET.PointLatLng(30.0000, 30.00000),
                    new Bitmap("images/2.png"));
```

thanks...

Comment: when i declare a variable as above can i reach a marker variable again as like `marker3[index] = new Bitmap("images/2.png");` ???

Comment: No, because you cannot assign the image to the marker as the image is a property of the marker.

Answer (score 1):

The problem updating the image of that marker is that the Image property is not publicly accessible, therefore you can not update the image that way.

There are two possibilities: first one is to replace the marker reference with a new one giving you the opportunity to set a new image and copying the position of the current marker. However that is not the clean way as you unnecessarily create a whole bunch of references only to dispose them right away depending on the use case. If it's a one-time update, then this approach is fine.

The preferable way is to derive from `GMapMarker` as the Google marker does (you can use that as a template, leaving out the whole google specific icon logic). Are you familiar with the concept of deriving? It will require some more effort but will be worth it, could help with that.

Also your main reference is probably the [project's github page](https://github.com/radioman/greatmaps/tree/master/GMap.NET.WindowsForms/GMap.NET.WindowsForms).

**EDIT**

```
using System.Drawing;

public class GImageMarker : GMapMarker
{
    public Bitmap Bitmap { get; set; }

    public GImageMarker(PointLatLng p, Bitmap Bitmap)
        : base(p)
    {
        this.Bitmap = Bitmap;
        Size = new System.Drawing.Size(Bitmap.Width, Bitmap.Height);
        Offset = new Point(-Size.Width / 2, -Size.Height);
    }

    public override void OnRender(Graphics g)
    {
         g.DrawImage(Bitmap, LocalPosition.X, LocalPosition.Y, Size.Width, Size.Height);
    }
}
```

Comment: i am declaring the marker again with new image but i dont like this way. i dont know c# well so i dont want to mess up GMap.NET library :D

Comment: That's fine, you're not gonna mess up anything :) By deriving you would extend the functionality of the marker. That extension is only going to live in your code, I can provide a sample once I'm back at a computer.

Comment: Added a minimal sample of a derived marker holding an image, add this class to your project and try if that works for you, please.

Comment: Did that help you any?

Comment: hi @rdoubleui . Sorry for late comment. I was so busy. I tried your code but you used 'DrawImageUnscaled' which you did not mentioned. I comment it out but when i reach my marker as 'markers.Markers[2].' there is not such a thing as 'GImageMarker'. I am sorry it could be my bad. I will be working on that. Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: You need to add the class to your project and then use it to create your marker: marker = new GImageMarker(position, imageName);

Comment: hi @rdoubleui . i added it and tried it out.                                   **GImageMarker marker4 = new GImageMarker(new GMap.NET.PointLatLng(20.71580, 11.50000),new Bitmap("images/orange.png"));
            markers.Markers.Add(marker4);
            gMapControl1.Overlays.Add(markers);** my application crushes.

Comment: I'm sorry, updated the `OnRender` method, was accidentally referencing wrong code. Pretty sure we get this working, if not let's take it off to the chat.

Comment: Also first add the overlay to the map control, then the marker to the overlay.

Comment: hi @rdoubleui . i added 'GImageMarker' and i dont see any error. i also added a marker as 'GImageMarker marker4 = new GImageMarker(new PointLatLng(39,40), new Bitmap("images/orange.png"));
            markers.Markers.Add(marker4);
            gMapControl1.Overlays.Add(markers);' when i start the application  i get the following error in Form1.Designer.cs :              resources.ApplyResources(this.gMapControl1, "gMapControl1");
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: not found.

Comment: hi @rdoubleui . i dont have enough rep to start a chat so i am waiting you sir :D

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/136716/gmap-question?tab=general# let's look at the code in detail in chat.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem, i contacted the creator of the library: radioman.
He referred some code called 'GMarkerArrow.' Here is the code:

```
namespace Demo.WindowsForms.CustomMarkers
{
    using System;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;
    using GMap.NET;
    using GMap.NET.WindowsForms;

    [Serializable]
    public class GMarkerArrow : GMapMarker, ISerializable
    {
        [NonSerialized]
        public Brush Fill = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(155, Color.Blue));

        //[NonSerialized]
        //public Pen Pen = new Pen(Brushes.Blue, 5);

        static readonly Point[] Arrow = new Point[] { new Point(-7, 7), new Point(0, -22), new Point(7, 7), new Point(0, 2) };

        public float Bearing = 0;
        private float scale = 1;

        public float Scale
        {
            get
            {
                return scale;
            }
            set
            {
                scale = value;

                Size = new System.Drawing.Size((int)(14 * scale), (int)(14 * scale));
                Offset = new System.Drawing.Point(-Size.Width / 2, (int)(-Size.Height / 1.4));
            }
        }

        public GMarkerArrow(PointLatLng p)
           : base(p)
        {
            Scale = (float)1.4;
        }

        public override void OnRender(Graphics g)
        {
            //g.DrawRectangle(Pen, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(LocalPosition.X, LocalPosition.Y, Size.Width, Size.Height));
            {
                g.TranslateTransform(ToolTipPosition.X, ToolTipPosition.Y);
                var c = g.BeginContainer();
                {
                    g.RotateTransform(Bearing - Overlay.Control.Bearing);
                    g.ScaleTransform(Scale, Scale);

                    g.FillPolygon(Fill, Arrow);
                }
                g.EndContainer(c);
                g.TranslateTransform(-ToolTipPosition.X, -ToolTipPosition.Y);
            }
        }

        public override void Dispose()
        {
            //if(Pen != null)
            //{
            //   Pen.Dispose();
            //   Pen = null;
            //}

            if (Fill != null)
            {
                Fill.Dispose();
                Fill = null;
            }

            base.Dispose();
        }

        #region ISerializable Members

        void ISerializable.GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        {
            base.GetObjectData(info, context);
        }

        protected GMarkerArrow(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
           : base(info, context)
        {
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Save this as GMarkerArrow.cs and add it to your project.
Add this to your Form1 code:

```
using Demo.WindowsForms.CustomMarkers;
```

Now you can use the new marker via following:

```
GMarkerArrow marker1 = new GMarkerArrow(new PointLatLng(-30, -40));
            marker1.ToolTipText = "blablabla";
            marker1.ToolTip.Fill = Brushes.Black;
            marker1.ToolTip.Foreground = Brushes.White;
            marker1.ToolTip.Stroke = Pens.Black;
            marker1.Bearing = 30; // Rotation angle
            marker1.Fill = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(155, Color.Blue)); // Arrow color
            markers.Markers.Add(marker1);
            gMapControl1.Overlays.Add(markers);
```

Also i want to thanks @rdoubleui , thanks you sir.
I hope this helps to everyone.

Answer (score 1):

GMapOverlay markersOverlay;

```
    private void AddOrUpdateMarker(string tag, double lat, double lng, Image NewImage)
    {

        Bitmap bmpmarker = (Bitmap)NewImage;

        var marker = markersOverlay.Markers.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Tag == tag);

        if(marker!=null)
        {
            markersOverlay.Markers.Remove(marker);
            gMapControl1.Refresh();
            marker = new GMarkerGoogle(new PointLatLng(lat, lng), bmpmarker);
            marker.Tag = tag;
            markersOverlay.Markers.Add(marker);
            gMapControl1.Refresh();
        }
        else
        {
            marker = new GMarkerGoogle(new PointLatLng(lat, lng), bmpmarker);
            marker.Tag = tag;
            markersOverlay.Markers.Add(marker);
            gMapControl1.Refresh();
        }


    }
```

Comment: what is markersOverlay you have not describe what it is